# Fail cloning git repository on WDCloud NAS/ Fail `git init`

Tags: git

I'm trying to create a local repository of my github file on a WDCloud in my office. PC in use run Ubuntu 20.04.

1. trying to clone using `git clone https://github.com/ZZZ/XXX`, failed, so tried `sudo git clone https://github.com/ZZZ/XXX` and got this error
2. Of course the git repo works as needed on same PC on a local drive.
3. `guy@cloud` is link to NAS directory.

see:

```
guy@desktop:~/guy@cloud/git2$ sudo git clone https://github.com/ZZZ/XXX
[sudo] password for guy: 
Cloning into 'Arduino'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 8646, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (8646/8646), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4145/4145), done.
remote: Total 24775 (delta 4906), reused 6922 (delta 3869), pack-reused 16129
Receiving objects: 100% (24775/24775), 43.12 MiB | 10.31 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (13500/13500), done.
fatal: cannot create directory at 'libraries/Adafruit_GFX_Library': Interrupted system call
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

guy@desktop:~/guy@cloud/git2$ git status
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home/guy)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
guy@desktop:~/guy@cloud/git2$ git restore --source=HEAD :/
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home/guy)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
guy@desktop:~/guy@cloud/git2$
```

** EDIT 1: Adding a forked git ( not mine ) , still SAME behavior**

```
guy@desktop:~/guy@cloud/git3$ sudo git clone https://github.com/ZZZ/Low-Power
Cloning into 'Low-Power'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 125, done.
remote: Total 125 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 125
Receiving objects: 100% (125/125), 41.64 KiB | 278.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (54/54), done.
guy@desktop:~/guy@cloud/git3$ git status
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home/guy)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
guy@desktop:~/guy@cloud/git3$
```

** EDIT 2: happens even when trying `git init` **

```
guy@desktop:~/guy@cloud/git4$ git init
error: chmod on /home/guy/guy@cloud/git4/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'
```

Comment: Don't use the `sudo` method; that leaves behind root-owned files, that you can't do anything to / with later. You'll need to `sudo chown -R` on the directories that got created under sudo permissions earlier, or sudo remove them, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This:

> ```
> fatal: cannot create directory at
> 'libraries/Adafruit_GFX_Library': Interrupted system call
> ```

is the source of the problem: a `mkdir` system call, trying to create that directory, is getting interrupted, almost certainly by Git's internal progress clock ticker, that decides when to print things like "30% done" or whatever.

This internal `EINTR` error is *not supposed to happen*.  The OS is supposed to *restart* the `mkdir` system call (given the way Git has arranged everything).  You have hit an OS bug.  Unfortunately, Git does not yet have a workaround for the OS bug.  You will need to do one of three things:

- Wait for the OS supplier to fix the bug.  (This could be a long wait.  In this case it's probably not the Linux kernel itself, but rather an add-on for the protocol exported by the NAS.)
- Wait for Git to have a workaround.  This will probably be in the next Git release as it's already underway.
- Clone the Git repository for Git, and build and test the `EINTR` fix versions.  That's the fastest way past this problem, but also the most work.  On the bright side you can get your name in the next Git release. :-)

Comment: did you see that it happens as described in EDIT2 ?

Comment: Can you explain more bullet #3 ?

Comment: The problem you're seeing in Edit-2 is a result of an earlier sudo: you've made files in your own area that you're not allowed to do anything with, that are not owned *by you*. To build your own Git, find any of the various replicas of the Git repository for Git. There's a canonical one at https://github.com/git/git that you can clone. Clone it, read through the build instructions for Linux, and build it.

Comment: To watch the progress of the EINTR fix attempts, look through (and/or sign on to) the Git mailing list. See https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitCommunity for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the issue you need to check:

```
fatal: cannot create directory at 'libraries/Adafruit_GFX_Library': Interrupted system call
```

Check for write permissions, or clone to a different location

Comment: NOT quite...see EDIT1 in my question.

Comment: Can you explain the sudo or try without it?

Comment: As worte in my question, tried and it fails :`git clone https://guthub.com/ZZZ/Low-Power
Cloning into 'Low-Power'...
error: chmod on /home/guy/guy@cloud/git3/Low-Power/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'`

Comment: Sorry I mean that instead of `sudo git clone https://github.com/ZZZ/Low-Power`, let's try `git clone https://github.com/ZZZ/Low-Power`

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote ( without `sudo`)

Comment: Hmm, this is what I see in your question:
`$ sudo git clone https://github.com/ZZZ/Low-Power`
But I see it now in the beginning of the question - sorry have missed that